# Why does the Boolean object have a public constructor in Java?

Tags: java, boolean

Documentation for the constructor `new Boolean(boolean value)` in Java states:

> Note: It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Unless a new instance is required, the static factory `valueOf(boolean)` is generally a better choice. It is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

If so, why is this constructor public and not deprecated? Is there ever a good reason to use this constructor instead of `Boolean.valueOf()`?

Comment: Integer has the same constructor new Integer(int value) http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28int%29

Comment: @Ict30 yes, but there are 4 billion possible objects that might get created for `Integer`. For `Boolean` there are only 2. There isn't a parallel there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`valueOf()` only got added in Java 1.4, so it would appear that the constructors exist for backwards compatibility.

[This ticket](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4941777) explains the reasons for not deprecating the constructors:

> Due to the disruption deprecating an API can have, currently an API
> has to be "actively hazardous" to be deprecated, like Thread.stop.
> While the use this constructor is certainly ill-advised, it doesn't
> rise (or sink) to the standard of hazardousness to be deprecated in
> the JDK.  In the future we may add a "denigration" facility to mark
> API elements that aren't quite so bad that they should be deprecated,
> but shouldn't be used in most cases.  This constructor would be a good
> candidate for denigration.

I can't think of a realistic scenario where using `Boolean` constructors would be the best way to do something useful.

Comment: Perhaps there needs to be an annotation `@discouraged` or something to indicate that it's not actively hazardous, but there's not really a good reason to do it.

Comment: What if one wants to have a lock token which can also encapsulate a bit flag?  One could write a custom type for that, but `Boolean` already exists.

Comment: @supercat I'd say `AtomicBoolean` might be a nicer choice for that. Or `Semaphore`, though that might be too fancy for a simple flag.

Comment: What is needed is a proper explaination of why this is bad. Everyone seems to be repeating parrot fashion that its bad, but there is very little infomation on why valueOf is better and why Oracle/Sun Microsystems did not just call valueOf from inside their constructors and not impact the developer.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, you will want to use `valueOf(boolean)` or even the `Boolean.TRUE` / `Boolean.FALSE` constants directly.

But think of a scenario where you want to use a private `Boolean` variable as a monitor for synchronizing threads. There you will need to make sure you use your own instance and have full control of it.

Comment: That's a pretty unimportant reason; there are literally thousands of other objects that can be used as monitors. I don't see keeping `Boolean` in that set as being high-priority.

Comment: unimportant but a good usecase, the valueof method may return duplicate objects, sometimes u dont want that

Comment: @Costi the point of `new Boolean(boolean value)` and `ValueOf(boolean)` is that you have a `boolean` and need a `Boolean` to use the constants you would need to use `b ? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE. How is that better than the first two methods?

Comment: @Hemal, "new" creates a new instance.  Since Booleans are immutable, it's usually a waste of an object  - valueOf() returns one of the two objects Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE.  Using Boolean.TRUE/FALSE is faster than valueOf() because the selection of true or false is done at compile-time.  Of course, if you don't know which it is till run-time, there's no advantage over valueOf().

Comment: @Ed, ok, I agree that `new` is not such a good idea. And I also agree that `Boolean.TRUE` is preferable over `Boolean.valueOf(true)` but that is not the point of discussion.

Comment: @Hemal: I mentioned `Boolean.TRUE` / `Boolean.FALSE` as an option only for the scenario when you're using `boolean` literals; so this is "the very point of discussion": use `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `Boolean.valueOf(true)`. When you have a `boolean b`, use `Boolean.valueOf(b)` which applies the conditional operator for you.

Comment: @dlev: Of course this is not *the reason why* that constructor is public (or the reason why it should be). I just imagined a scenario where this could be useful. The way I see it, every primitive wrapper provides a constructor taking a primitive and some of them (like `Boolean` and `Integer`) also provide a `valueOf` factory method in order to be able to cache instances when a new instance is not required.

Answer (score 5):

Another, not necessarily good reason would probably be to simply keep it consistent with the other native wrappers.

Comment: Have some confidence! That's a pretty decent reason.

Comment: I was mostly doubting the Java creators, not myself :)

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 9, the `Boolean(boolean)` constructor **has been deprecated**; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).

For those who care about the history, there was a longstanding [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4941777) that called for the deprecation of the constructor.  It was formally proposed in [JEP 277](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/277) along with a number of other deprecations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it hasn't been deprecated is that Java maintains backwards compatibility to version 1.0

I can't think of a good reason to use the constructor.

Comment: Marking it deprecated wouldn't stop it from being backwards compatible though. Actually, that's the whole point of it.

Comment: Java doesn't maintain backwards-compatibility to version 1.0 though: several JDKs (off the top of my head, 1.4 and 1.7) introduced constructs that can't be run on earlier JREs. They're just very reluctant to break anything, and decided this awful constructor wasn't *dangerous enough* to warrant breaking backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @amalloy That would be forwards compatibility; backwards compatibility is the guarantee that constructs runnable on earlier JREs can be run on later ones (and is one of the reasons Java generics are implemented via type erasure and raw types are still a thing).