# Why do we need Boolean(boolean) constructor in java?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there is any legacy reason or common use case, because I do not see any use for this constructor.

Why use this:

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(var);
```

when we have:

```
Boolean b = var; // Java will auto-box into Boolean.TRUE / Boolean.FALSE
```

or

```
Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(var);
```

The documentation states that *it is rarely appropriate to use this constructor, unless a new instance is required*.

When do we need require a new instance?

Comment: can't we have several ways to do the same thing?

Comment: When you want two `Boolean`s that do not compare reference equal? Though this question was already asked almost three years ago: [Why does the Boolean object have a public constructor in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434084/why-does-the-boolean-object-have-a-public-constructor-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might use a distinct instance:

```
private static Boolean NO_VALUE = new Boolean(false);

private Boolean foo = NO_VALUE;

public setFoo(Boolean foo) {  // may be TRUE, FALSE or null
    if(foo = NO_VALUE) {
        // initialization logic
    }
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

This may not be the best use case, but I think it demonstrates why a distinct instance is not completely useless.